# Set inactive tab tint color

Tags: xamarin.ios

[image]

How do you set the inactive tint color with Xamarin.iOS?

There are solutions for Xcode, but can't use them in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For The bottom text** :

```
// This will change the text's color when the item is unselected
var attributes = new UITextAttributes();   
attributes.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
TabBarItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(attributes, UIControlState.Normal);

var selectedAttributes = new UITextAttributes();
selectedAttributes.TextColor = UIColor.White;
TabBarItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(selectedAttributes, UIControlState.Selected);
```

**For the icon**:

```
// This will let the icon show the image's original color(instead of the gray) when the item is unselected
TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("imageName").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
```

You can also use the same method to set the image when the item is selected:

```
TabBarItem.SelectedImage = UIImage.FromBundle("imageName").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
```

Or just use `TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;`.

Comment: Where to put this code? I tried in `class AboutPageRenderer : PageRenderer { public override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) { /* pasted code here */ } }`. But it had no effect.

Comment: You can create a custom renderer for your `TabbedPage`, in the event `ViewWillAppear(bool animated)` use this code like: `this.ViewControllers[0].TabBarItem...//use my code above`